# Error en arrays

Tags: java, array

```
package acnumeroletras;
public class CnumeroLetras 
{
    private double n, um2;
    private int u, d, c, um;
    private int d1, d2, u1, c2, m1, m2, m3, c3, um1,DmC;
    private String cadena = " ";
    private String unidades[] = {"  ", "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete", "ocho", "nueve"};
    private String decenas[] = {"  ", "diez", "veinte", "treinta", "cuarenta", "cincuenta", "sesenta", "setenta", "ochenta", "noventa"};
    private String decenas1[] = {"diez", "once", "doce", "trece", "catorce", "quince", "dieciseis", "diecisiete", "dieciocho", "diecinueve"};
    private String centenas[] = {" ", "cien", "doscientos", "trescientos", "cuatrocientos", "quinientos", "seiscientos", "setecientos", "ochocientos", "novecientos"};
    private String unidadesMill[] = {"", "", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete", "ocho", "nueve"};
    private String millonesstr[] = {"", "un", "dos","tres","cuatro","cindo","seis","siete","ocho","nueve"};

    public CnumeroLetras(int n) 
    {
        this.n = n;
    }

    private void calculaUnidades() {
        double unidad1 = n%10;
        int unidad3 = (int) unidad1;
        if((u1==1))
            cadena=cadena+"  ";
        else
            cadena=cadena+unidades[unidad3]+" ";
 //       System.out.println(unidades[unidad3]+" ");
    }

    private void calculaDecenas() 
{
//        d = (int) ((n - (c * 100) - u) / 10);

        double Cdecenas1 = n%100;
        double Cdecenas3 = Cdecenas1/10;
        int decenas4 = (int) Cdecenas3;
 //       System.out.println(decenas[decenas4]+" ");

    switch (decenas4) 
    {
            case 1:
                double Ucase1 = n%10;
                int RUcase1 = (int) Ucase1;
  //              System.out.println(decenas1[RUcase1]);
                cadena = cadena + decenas1[RUcase1];                                    //once, doce, trece etc...
                u1 = 1;
                break;

            case 2:
 //               d1 = (int) (n % 10);
                double Ucase2 = n%10;
                int RUcase2 = (int) Ucase2;
                if ((RUcase2 == 0)) 
                {
                    cadena = cadena + decenas[d] + " ";
                } 
                else 
                {
                    cadena = cadena + "veinti";
                    cadena = cadena + unidades[d1] + " ";                   //veinti+numero
                    u1 = 1;
                }
                System.out.println(u);

                break;

            default:
                    switch (decenas4)
                    {    
                        case 0:
                            {    
                                cadena = cadena + "  ";                         //si decenas=0, deja decenas en blanco
                            }    
                        break;

                        default: 
                            {
//                       d2 = (int) (n % 10);
                               double UcaseD = n%10;
                               int RUcaseD = (int) UcaseD;
                               if ((RUcaseD == 0)) {
                                   cadena = cadena + decenas[decenas4];                     //en caso de que decenas>0 y unidades=0 solo muestra las decenas
                               } else {
                                   cadena = cadena + decenas[decenas4] + " " + "y" + " ";           //treinta y... en adelante
                               }
 //                               System.out.println(d);
                            }
                        break;

                    }
                break;

    }
}

    private void calculaCentenas() {

        double ncentenas = (n%1000);  
        double ncentenas3 = ncentenas/100;
        int ncentenas2 = (int) ncentenas3;

        double Cdecenas1 = n%100;
    double Cdecenas3 = Cdecenas1/10;

        if((Cdecenas3>0) && (ncentenas2==1))
            cadena=cadena+"ciento"+" "; 
        else
            cadena=cadena+centenas[ncentenas2]+" ";

    }

    private void calculaUMillar() 
    {

        double nmillar = n/1000;
        int nmillar2 = (int) nmillar;

        if ((DmC==1))
            {
                    cadena=cadena+" ";   
            }
        else
            {
            cadena = cadena + unidadesMill[nmillar2]+" "+"mill"+"  ";

            }
    }
    private void calculaDMillar()
    {
        double Dmillar2 = n/10000;
        int Dmillar = (int) Dmillar2;

        System.out.println(Dmillar2);
        System.out.println(Dmillar);
        cadena=cadena+decenas[Dmillar];
        System.out.println(decenas[Dmillar]);

        switch (Dmillar) 
    {
            case 1:
                double umcase1 = n/1000;
                int Rumcase1 = (int) umcase1;
                cadena = cadena + decenas1[Rumcase1]+" mil ";                                   //once, doce, trece etc...
                DmC = 1;
                break;

            case 2:
 //               d1 = (int) (n % 10);
 //               int RUcase2 = (int) Ucase2;
 //               
                double umcase2 = n/1000;
                int Rumcase2 = (int) umcase2;
                if ((Rumcase2 == 0)) 
                {
                    cadena = cadena + decenas[Dmillar] +" mil ";
                } 
                else 
                {
                    cadena = cadena + "veinti";
                    cadena = cadena + unidades[Rumcase2] + " ";                 //veinti+numero
                    DmC = 1;
                }
//               System.out.println(u);

                break;

            default:
                    switch (Dmillar)
                    {    
                        case 0:
                            {    
                                cadena = cadena + "  ";                         //si decenas=0, deja decenas en blanco
                            }    
                        break;

                        default: 
                            {
//                               d2 = (int) (n % 10);
//                               double UcaseD = n%10;
//                               int RUcaseD = (int) UcaseD;

                                 double umcaseD = n/1000;
                                   int RumcaseD = (int) umcaseD;

                               if ((RumcaseD == 0)) {
                                   cadena = cadena + decenas[Dmillar]+" mil ";                      //en caso de que decenas>0 y unidades=0 solo muestra las decenas
                               } else {
                                   cadena = cadena + decenas[Dmillar] + " " + "y" + " ";            //treinta y... en adelante
                               }
 //                               System.out.println(d);
                            }
                        break;

                    }
                break;

        }


    }
    private void calculaMillones(){

        double nmillones = (n%10000);
        double nmillones3 = nmillones/1000;
        int nmillones2 = (int) nmillones3;
        if((n<1000000))
            cadena = cadena +"";
        else
            {
                switch(nmillones2)
                {
                    case 1:
                        cadena = cadena + millonesstr[nmillones2]+" "+"millon";
                    break;

                    default:
                        cadena = cadena + millonesstr[nmillones2]+" "+"millones";
                    break;
                } 
            }
    }

    public String regresaDescripcion() {

            calculaMillones();
            calculaDMillar();
            calculaUMillar();
            calculaCentenas();
            calculaDecenas();
            calculaUnidades();

        return cadena;
    }

}
```

Introduzco los valores en la clase `main`, aquí entran en la variable `n` y a la hora de poner números con decenas de millar, me da un error
este es el código  del error introduciendo el numero `10000`

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   10    at
>   acnumeroletras.CnumeroLetras.calculaUMillar(CnumeroLetras.java:124)
>     at
>   acnumeroletras.CnumeroLetras.regresaDescripcion(CnumeroLetras.java:227)
>     at acnumeroletras.ACnumeroletras.main(ACnumeroletras.java:13)

El programa funciona sin problemas de `9999` hacia a abajo.

Comment: cual es la linea 124? probaste debugueando el programa? el error es claro.

Comment: La variable `Rumcase1` tiene valor  mayor a 9 para que salte ese error. dado que al querer obtener `decenas1[Rumcase1]` intenta obtener `decenas1[10]` que está fuera del rango , puede obtener desde `decenas1[0]` hasta `decenas1[9]`

Comment: muchas gracias!!!!!!! :D